# Function parameter type return specific value

Tags: typescript

Currently I'm passing in a callback to parse raw values to specific generic types

```
protected constructValue<TResult>(key: string, parser: Function): TResult {
    const rawValue: string = /* assign raw value here */;

    return parser(rawValue);
}
```

Is there a way I can make sure that the parser function has to be a callback that returns a value of the generic type? So this would work

`constructValue<number>('myKey', Number)`

but this wouldn't

`constructValue<number>('myKey', value => value === 'true')`

because the parser returns a boolean and not a number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can limit the type of Parser from a generic `Function` to something like:

```
parser: (...args: any) => TResult
```

or even better define what the args are:

```
parser: (rawValue: string) => TResult
```